# The commit message pane of WebStorm is unable to edit

Tags: intellij-idea, svn, webstorm, commit

WebStorm 2021.1.3 on Windows.

[image]

I've tried to modify the setting params.

[image]

Comment: WebStorm 2021.1.3 is outdated. The most recent version is 2022.3. So does the problem occur with an up-to-date version?

Comment: It seem sthat you have resized your commit window at some point. You should be able to grab a line next to a "Commit message" and drag it in order to resize the commit message field